# Distinct in z3 SMT and python

Tags: z3, z3py

My question is that Does "Distinct" works in z3 python?. I've compared the following code and it seem not giving the same results:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (distinct x y))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The result was:

```
sat

  (model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    0)
  (define-fun x () Int
    1)
  )
```

I've added negative assertion just to test and the result was unsat which is correct:

```
(assert (= x y))

unsat
Z3(6, 10): ERROR: model is not available
```

But when I use z3 in python it give me always sat as follows:

```
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
Distinct(x, y)
s = Solver
s = Solver() 
s.check()
```

when I add the following assertion It should give me unsat but It returns sat:

```
s.add(x == y)
[y = 0, x = 0]
```

Is this means that I used wrong syntax ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Distinct' function only creates a term, it doesn't add itself to the solver. Here's an example that works for me:

```
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
d = Distinct(x, y)

s = Solver()
s.add(d) # SAT without this one, UNSAT with
s.add(x == y)
print s
print s.check()
```